# Find the most similar vector/string in Matlab

Tags: string, matlab

Consider that I have some vectors (or strings) of numbers which generally have different length, eg `x=[1 2 3 4 3 3 3 2 5]`.

Now, for a new vector **y** I want to find which one of the existing vectors **x** is the most similar.

Any idea?

**The complete Problem:**

I want to predict a time serie with some Neural Networks. Atevery step all the networks predict the next value of the serie. When the real value comes, the network that did the best prediction wins and I write its number to the vector X. After i finish with the timeserie1 i will have generate a vector X1 and each element of it will represend the best NN.

Now consider that i have 10 time series , so 10 X vectors. For a new one time serie Y i will do the same procedure. I want to define the kind of the Y using its similarity between this and the X vectors. I think the most importand aspect is the succession of the NN. I need for output something like a number or percentage of similarity.
eg:

X1= [ 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6 ]

X2=[1 2 3 4 5 6 1 2 3 4 5 6]

Y=[1 1 1 2 2 3 4 5 5 6 6]

Then Y is more similar to X1

Comment: define most similar, I can make up 12 definitions of similarity... in other words what are the weights that you give to different aspects of similarity?

Comment: Perhaps share with us the expected output

Comment: You must define your definition from similarity. Do you want close number? If it has different length, is it OK ?

Comment: I want to predict a time serie with some Neural Networks. Atevery step all the networks predict the next value of the serie. When the real value comes, the network that did the best prediction wins and I write its number to the vector X. After i finish with the timeserie1 i will have generate a vector X1 and each element of it will represend the best NN. 

Now consider that i have 10 time series , so 10 X vectors. For a new one time serie Y i will do the same procedure. I want to define the kind of the Y using its similarity between this and the X vectors ( the succession of the NN)

Comment: Do you have 10 separate vectors? ***Please*** Use a  matrix if the size is same. If it is not, use a cell array.

Comment: @Alexandros x1 and x2 have 12 elements, whereas y has 11. Is that intended?

Comment: The length of the vectors is NOT the same. Generally no vector has the same lingth with someone else, neither X or Y

Comment: @pkpkpk Yes it is

Comment: @Alexandros Perhaps `Y=[Y Y(end)]; nx1 = nnz(X1==Y); nx2 = nnz(X2==Y)` for index wise comparison between them for the example you showed, by adjusting y to have the same elements as the other two vectors